# Miscalculated and booked an extra day in Denmark on a 10 day visa

Tags: visas, overstaying, denmark, nepali-citizens

I am travelling to Denmark today, and will be there tomorrow.

My visa period is for 10 days, from 4th June 2016 to 14th June. I miscalculated the days, and my return flight is on 14th June (so, in 11 days).

This would mean I would overstay my visa by 1 day.

What are my options?

Comment: Hi there sagar, welcome to Travel.SE. I've submitted a suggested edit for your post to clarify it a bit, and also to add some additional tags. I'm assuming from the [tag:nepal] tag that you're a Nepali citizen, so I've changed that to the [tag:nepali-citizens] tag. Please advise (or re-edit) if this is incorrect.

Comment: If your visa expires on 14/6 and you depart on 14/6 then you have not overstayed!